# HTTP3 Client for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-io, flutter-http, http3

Is There a **HTTP3 client** for dart? There is [Flupke](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/flupke) in Java, [Aioqic](https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic) in python but  I didn't find one for dart as well as flutter

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38595

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, Thank you

Answer (score -3):

If you need a persistent connection you can use the Client class provided by the http Library:
https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client-class.html

Try out this package, to make the consumption of HTTP resources easier: https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: http/3 or QUIC is different with http/1 protocol